# Get All Parents of Hierarchical Category in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table that looks like the following

```
cat_id  | name            |   parent_id |   Level
-------------------------------------------------
1         cat1                0             1
2         subcat1             1             2
3         subcat1-subcat      2             3
```

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to get the **parent** categories of `cat_id 3`, so my result set will look like this

```
cat_id  | name            |   parent_id |   Level
--------------------------------------------------
1         cat1                0             1
2         subcat1             1             2
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have recursive syntax - see this link for more info: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html

Comment: Is it just me or isn't the `Level` column redundant?

Comment: @Yzmir: Depends how you need to slice this data. You could compute it but computing it could be rather ugly (especially in MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do multiple queries. One for each level up you want to go (or write it as a stored procedure).

The most efficient way is not to use what's called the "adjacency list model" (what you are using) and instead switch to "nested sets".

Googling for "nested set" will give you lots of info. It will take you some time to get used to it though, and to write the code for handling it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but unfortunately there is no way to do this in single query. so you have to either write a function or a stored procedure which can get all parent categories.
algo will be as follows

```
**childs** = 3
Loop (not done)
 Get immediate parents of **childs**, 
 save(concat) them in a *return* variable
 update **childs** = immediate parents
REPEAT
```

*return* will contain all parents(flat) of given category

1) FUNCTION : in case of function you will return a string value as function can not return more than 1 values so your result will be some thing like "1,2". but again this will not full fill our purpose as we have to use this result in a query

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name where id IN ("1,2") ORDER BY LEVEL
```

so instead we will return our result as a regular expression ;) and that is "^(1|2)$"

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_categories WHERE cat_id REGEXP "^(1|2)$" ORDER BY level;
```

2) STORED PROCEDURE: in case of stored procedure we can prepare a statement dynamically and upon executing that query we will have our required result.

for more detail on stored procedure pleas have a look on following tutorial.

[Get all nested parents of a category – MySQL](http://devbank.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/get-all-nested-parents-of-a-category-mysql/)